# Kendo Grid rowTemplate k-button click function not defined

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using K-button in Kendo Grid. For colouring each row I was supposed to use rowTemplate and altRowTemplate options. the only problem is that click function is not binding properly to the buttons.

I am getting the following error,

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: viewProfile is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):1)

Code here,

```
  myGridOptions({
    columns: [
      { field: 'name', title: 'Name', width: '160px'},
      { field: 'address', title: 'address'},
      { field: 'occupation', title: 'Occupation' },          
      { field: 'location', title: 'Location'},
      { field: 'salary', title: 'Salary' },
      { field: 'company', title: 'Company'},
      { field: 'phone', title: 'Phone'},
      //{ field: 'button', title: ' ' }
      { command: { text: 'View Profile', click: viewProfile }, title: ' ', width: '160px' }          
    ],
    dataSource: OccData,
    rowTemplate: '<tr style="background-color: rgb(246,246,246)" data-uid="#= uid #">'+
      '<td>#: name # </td>' +          
      '<td>#: address #</td>' +
      '<td>#: occupation #</td>' +
      '<td>#: location #</td>' +          
      '<td>#: salary #</td>' +
      '<td>#: company #</td>' +          
      '<td> #: phone#</td>' +
      '<td>#: education #</td>' +          
      '<td><button class="k-button" onclick="viewProfile();">View Profile</button></td>'+         
      '</tr>',
      altRowTemplate: '<tr style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255)" data-uid="#= uid #">'+
      '<td>#: name # </td>' +          
      '<td>#: address #</td>' +
      '<td>#: occupation #</td>' +
      '<td>#: location #</td>' +          
      '<td>#: salary #</td>' +
      '<td>#: company #</td>' +          
      '<td> #: phone#</td>' +
      '<td>#: education #</td>' +          
      '<td><button class="k-button" onclick="viewProfile();">View Profile</button></td>'+         
      '</tr>',        
    overflow: false
  });
```

I have referred few links, but could not find the solution to use click function in rowTemplate.

Any suggestion from Kendo developers!! would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got it!!

```
    <div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "age" },
    {template: "<button class=\"show\">Show</button>"}
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
    { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
  ],
  dataBound: function(e) {
    //console.log("dataBound");
    this.element.find(".show").bind("click", function() {
    alert("Clicked");
  });
  }
});
</script>
```

Thanks to, https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound

It may help Someone!!

Answer (score 0):

In your columns definition you are specifying the click event `viewProfile`. Do you have a JavaScript function named `viewProfile`?

Comment: Yes. I have the function.